# SDK Manager Invalid Argument: Connect

Tags: android, eclipse, facebook

I'm trying to install (API9) to import the Facebook SDK into my project and when I use the SDK Manager in Eclipse to Install the package, I get the error: Download Interrupted: Invalid Argument: Connect. This error appears after SDK Manager attempts to Install each part of the API9 Package.

Do I have something wrong with my connection. My firewall is completely off and no Anti-Virus is running. I am using a cell phone Hot Spot to my laptop, is there a chance that would cause a connection issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try this offline Android SDK Installation method from this website:
http://qdevarena.blogspot.in/2010/05/download-android-sdk-standalone-for.html